# how to append a div between two anchor elements

Tags: javascript, anchor

i have got two anchor elements:

```
<a onclick="PostMenuAction('abc');" class="port" title="AddPort" id="lnkPort">port</a>
```

and

```
<a onclick="PostMenuAction('def');" class="crop" title="AddCrop" id="lnkCrop">crop</a>
```

Now i want a div with a small image to be inserted between the two.

so it will be

```
<a onclick="PostMenuAction('abc');" class="port" title="AddPort" id="lnkPort">port</a>
 <div id="additionaldiv"> <img src="" id="additional img" /> </div>
<a onclick="PostMenuAction('def');" class="crop" title="AddCrop" id="lnkCrop">crop</a>
```

Can you please help me out adding the same?
my pleasure if this solved using javascript

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add div between two anchor elements on some click event?

Comment: do you want to make like this:
<a id="first"></a><div id="additional"></div><a id="second"></a>  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. You can make this into a JavaScript Function:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "/path/to/image";
div.appendChild(img);
var a = document.getElementById("lnkCrop");
a.parentNode.insertBefore(div,a);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a JavaScript function to do it:

```
function addImageBefore(path, id) {
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        img = document.createElement('img'),
        refElement = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!refElement) {// Presumably atypical, hence not worrying about creating above
        return null;
    }
    img.src = path;
    div.appendChild(img);
    refElement.parentNode.insertBefore(div, refElement);
    return div;
}
```

Call it in your case like this:

```
addImageBefore("path/to/img", "lnkCrop");
```

Put that call in whatever event handler or what-have-you you want to trigger the addition with.

More in the DOM specs: [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/), [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/), [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<a onclick="PostMenuAction('abc');" class="port" title="AddPort" id="lnkPort">port</a>
<div><img src="small.gif" alt="" /></div>
<a onclick="PostMenuAction('def');" class="crop" title="AddCrop" id="lnkCrop">crop</a>
```

Comment: I think the question was asking how to do it in javascript?

Comment: @James Khoury: My (subtle) point is that the question *wasn't* asking how to do it in javascript...

Comment: Lol! Well I guess it was more implied than stated.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a javascript to do this. Below is the way to do this feature.

```
document.getElementById("lnkPort").innerHTML = document.getElementById("lnkPort").innerHTML+'<div><h1>Test</h1></div>';
```

Comment: it would be <a onclick="PostMenuAction('abc');" class="port" title="AddPort" id="lnkPort">port<div><h1>Test</h1></div></a> , right?

Comment: actualy the question is ambigous, because i think the question is how to insert div between the two anchor, i mean like <a id="first"></a><div id="additional"></div><a id="second"></a> but i don't know, cmiiw :)

Comment: @bungdito : It will actually like that only as you have mentioned in your comment. If you want to see it, after the javascript add a line **alert(document.getElementById("lnkPort").innerHTML)**

Comment: Anchor tags are inline elements and div tags are block elements, so the code produces invalid markup.

Comment: I have tested it and it works fine. There is no such comment or error like invalid markup.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function makeSlide() {
  document.getElementById("lnkPort").innerHTML = document.getElementById("lnkPort").innerHTML+'<div><h1>Test</h1></div>';
  alert(document.getElementById("lnkPort").innerHTML);
 }
</script>
</head>
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="javascript:makeSlide()">
 <a onclick="PostMenuAction('abc');" class="port" title="AddPort" id="lnkPort">port</a>

 <a onclick="PostMenuAction('def');" class="crop" title="AddCrop" id="lnkCrop">crop</a>